# React-native open link in browser and return to app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've developing an app in react-native that should communicate with a gateway for payments, after finishing the payment process (success or failure) I need to show an alert to user. For this purpose, I open a link in **`WebView`** and after that I get return's url with **`onNavigationStateChange`** and show success or failure message.

But, this flow for **security** issues must be done in a **default device browser**.

Current Code:

```
const BASEURL = 'https://gatewayURL/?ID=';
let Token = null;
let paymentAccepted = null;
let paymentFactorId = null;

class Gateway extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func,
    navigation: PropTypes.any,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getPaymentStatus());
  }


  _onLoad(webViewState) {
    let url = webViewState.url.toString();
    let isResponseValid = url.includes('backFromGateway');
    if(isResponseValid){
      if(this.props.checkedPaymentStatus != 'checked' ){
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.props.dispatch(setPaymentStatus('checked'));

          let splitedURL = url.split("/");
          paymentFactorId = splitedURL[splitedURL.length -2];
          if(splitedURL[splitedURL.length - 1] === '0'){
            paymentAccepted = true;
            this.props.dispatch(setGatewayResponse('done', paymentFactorId));
          }
          else {
            paymentAccepted = false;
            this.props.dispatch(setGatewayResponse('rejected', paymentFactorId));
          }


          this.props.navigation.navigate('BackFromGateway', { title: '' })
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  }


  render() {
    const { addNewOrderGatewayToken, checkedPaymentStatus } = this.props;
    token = addNewOrderGatewayToken;
    let view = null;
    if(checkedPaymentStatus !== 'checked'){
      view =  <WebView onNavigationStateChange={this._onLoad.bind(this)} style={styles.container} source={{ uri: `${BASEURL}${token}`  }}/>
    }
    else{
      view = <View></View>
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {view}
      </View>      
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I quite do not grasp what is your reasoning and meaning behind webviews security issues? Is there some article related to this? Webview uses same engine as Chrome on mobile and I would not see how Webview would get affected in terms of security.

Comment: @JimiPajala Our local store only accepts this way for apps that include online payment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you can make callbacks from the gateway website, then I recommend to use deep linking to handle flow between app and browser. Basically, your app will open the gateway website for payment, and depending on payment result, the website will make a callback to the app using its deep link. App then will listen to the link, take out necessary information and continue to proceed.

What you need to do is:

Set up deep linking in your app. You should follow the guide from official website ([here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html)) to enable it. Let pick a random URL here for linking, e.g. `gatewaylistener`

Set the necessary callbacks from gateway to your app. In your case, since you need to handle successful payment and failed payment, you can add 2 callbacks, e.g. `gatewaylistener://success?id={paymentId}` and `gatewaylistener://error?id={paymentId}`

Finally, you need to listen to web browser from the app. One way to do that is add listener right inside the component opening the gateway.

```
// setup
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      this.handleOpenURL(url)
    }
  }).catch(err => {})
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL)
}

// open your gateway
async openGateWay = () => {
  const { addNewOrderGatewayToken } = this.props
  const url = `${BASEURL}${addNewOrderGatewayToken}`
  const canOpen = await Linking.canOpenURL(url)
  if (canOpen) {
    this.props.dispatch(setPaymentStatus('checked'))
    Linking.openURL(url)
  }
}

// handle gateway callbacks
handleOpenURL = (url) => {
  if (isSucceedPayment(url)) { // your condition
    // handle success payment
  } else {
    // handle failure
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, you said for setting up the deep linking we need to have a URL right? this url can be specified in Intent-filter and data attribute?  like this?    `<data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />`  and put gatewaylistener://success?id={paymentId} in this data?

Comment: It should be `<data android:scheme="gatewaylistener" />` since the scheme you wanna use is not http, but `gatewaylistener`. I suggest you to look into some good examples around, like https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e to know how to call & setup deep linking.

Comment: Why my scheme not http? I need to listen a URL from browser and if the user redirected to that URL, my app should open that screen and show success/failure message. Is it right or i made a mistake? Now, i send a user to browser for payment but after finishing the payment my app doesn't respond.

Comment: Scheme value is to let Android system know what it can do when a web URI intent is invoked. Your app does not listen to URL from browser, but listens to the callback from the gateway website. If you do it correctly, then even a link tag like `<a href="gatewaylistener://success">Open app</a>` can open your app without trouble.

Comment: Of course, the scheme can be http or whatever you want, but you have to set it up properly in your app first to make sure system know what to do when the URI is called in browser. Use non-http scheme is common method to distinguish app scheme from normal web scheme.

Comment: Aha, okey. Thanks. I'll check it again. I need to change my gateway callback a little

Comment: how we can have this code with hooks?

Answer (score 2):

For authentication purposes, using a deep linking redirection for example, you can use an embedded browser with **Chrome Custom Tabs** from Android and **SafariViewController** from iOS, check the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser) component to support both platforms with the same code (**Linking** is already used internally to detect the deep link redirection).

As you can see from the example folder, you can use a custom deep link configured from your app **(AndroidManifest for Android and Info.plist for iOS)**:

```
  getDeepLink (path = '') {
    const scheme = 'my-demo'
    const prefix = Platform.OS === 'android' ? `${scheme}://demo/` : `${scheme}://`
    return prefix + path
  }

  async tryDeepLinking () {
    const redirectToURL = `https://proyecto26.github.io/react-native-inappbrowser/`
    const redirectUrl = this.getDeepLink('home')
    const url = `${redirectToURL}?redirect_url=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)}`
    try {
      if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
        const result = await InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, redirectUrl)
        await this.sleep(800)
        Alert.alert('Response', JSON.stringify(result))
      } else {
        // You can use Linking directly for iOS < 9
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Something’s wrong with the app :(')
    }
  }
```