# Redirect to React Native app from Node.js server

Tags: node.js, react-native

When a user signs up via my react-native app an email is sent out to confirm their email address, which will enable them to log into the app.

At the moment I redirect to a web page that confirms email confirmation has been successful.

What I would like to do is redirect them to the login page of the app with a message that says confirmation of email has been successful (ideally I would log them in too which would make the user journey a lot smoother).

This is my controller server side at present (Node.js):

```
import User from '../../models/user.js'

export default async(req, res) => {
  const { token, permalink } = req.params;

  User.findbyPermalink(permalink, async (err, user) => {
    if (user && user.verification_token === token) {
      User.updateVerifiedTrue(permalink, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      });
      res.redirect('/email_verified');
    }
  });
};
```

Route:

```
app.get('/email_verified', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).type("html").send("<h1>Email Confirmed - You can now log in<h1>");
});
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: I think you need [linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) for your purpose. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51358906/8196025] This might also be helpful for you.

Comment: @Richlewis check new solution

Comment: Editor's feedback: this question received an anonymous downvote (not mine). While we can't know the reasoning where it has not been given, we can perhaps guess. The original phrasing in this question was a bit needy, the question was rather vague, and it seemed that a request for free work was being made. This general problem seems to pervade all of your questions, and it is rather unusual for someone who has had a Stack Overflow account for over ten years.

Comment: I say this not to offend you, but because you could persevere for several more years under a mindset that, unknown to you, undermines your labours and efforts. There is a concept called "personal agency" (also known as "self actualisation", from Maslow's Hierarchy of Needs) where a person develops a habit of asking questions of the form "how can I do this" or "what do I need to achieve". It is specific and action-oriented, and lets readers know that you aren't giving them your project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is wide, let's break it into small subproblems.

#### Registering your domain URL for Universal Linking

You need to register an email verification URL in order device OS automatically opens the app when that link is visited.

Configuration instruction varies depend on if you use either Expo or Bare React Native CLI

Expo CLI - https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#universaldeep-links-without-a-custom-scheme

React Native CLI - https://rossbulat.medium.com/deep-linking-in-react-native-with-universal-links-and-url-schemes-7bc116e8ea8b

#### Configure React Navigation Routes for  Deep Linking

React Navigation parse weblink `https://yourservername/path/to/ressoure?token=zzxboiu7897665enhgt7&emailVerified=true`  and navigate to the corresponding screen with dynamic parameters. Follow [instruction here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the links have helped. I can open my app now via a redirect from my server. Next part is sending params :-)

Comment: I am trying to go back to myapp://app/login from my expressjs using res.redirect(myapp://app/login), but it shows Cannot GET / auth/callback/myapp://app/login

Comment: app  custom app scheme  like `myapp://` not recognized by web servers. Browsers can detect  your app scheme  as it was registered by your device OS.

Comment: Host a simple HTML page at `https://your-server.com/app/login.html` then run automatic page redirect  script to  when page load  `window.location.replace("myapp://app/login)`